# How can I set up a t-test that tests whether one sample is larger than another in R?

Tags: r, sample

I was given two sets of measurements of air particulates (24 samples, taken hourly) at two locations. I know how to test whether the means are the same (they are not), but I'm tasked with testing the Ho that the particulate concentration is higher at (building1_air) than it is at (building2_air).
This is my first time working with R software (or any, for that matter).
What should the t-test command (if that's the right term) look like to compare the two sets of samples? I'm grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1):

```
t.test(building1_air,building2_air, alternative="g")
```

because your Alternative Hyp. is not the default one (wich is two tail test)

Answer (score 0):

From [Quick-R](http://www.statmethods.net/stats/ttest.html):

```
t.test(building1_air,building2_air)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are these counts of particulates? if so, a poisson test might be what you are looking for. for a single sample you can use the function `poisson.test` to create confidence intervals. To compare rates, you can use `binom.test`